# Using tail on a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to use `tail` on a `data.table` like I do on a data frame. Is that possible? If not what's more efficient way to get the tail of a data table?

```
mainDF= data.frame(name= c("a","b","c","d"))
tail(mainDF,1)["name"]
dt<-as.data.table(mainDF)
setkey(dt, name )
tail(dt,1)["name"]
```

output

```
> mainDF= data.frame(name= c("a","b","c","d"))
> tail(mainDF,1)["name"]
  name
4    d
> dt<-as.data.table(mainDF)
> setkey(dt, name )
> tail(dt,1)["name"]
   name
1:   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

In current version of `data.table`, you can get very close:

```
tail(dt, 1L)[ , "name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As on date, it can be done with,

`last(dt, 5)`

will give you 5 last rows of your data...

the signature is `last(x, n=1L, ...)`, you can play with `n`

for detailed usage please refer to [last: First/last item of an object](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.15.0/topics/last)